# How to parameter passing get method in flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart, get

I am try to parameter passing using get method and i have create a one model getting jsondata but i am getting 500 error. But postman working here attached my code please resolve my problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gmww.png)

```
sigin() async {
  var params = {
    "username": "XYZ_32950",
    "password": "XYZ_39510",
    "ProjectName": "ABCD"
  };

  Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://abcd.abcd.co.in/api/login");
  uri.replace(queryParameters: params);

  var response = await http
      .get(uri, headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json"});
  print('---- status code: ${response.statusCode}');
  var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
  if (jsonData != null) {
    User data = User.fromJson("user");
    return data;
  } else {
    isLoading = false;

    return null;
  }
}
```

```
class User {
  String _loginStatus;
  String _Status;
  String _DivisionName;
  User.fromJson(jsonData) {
    this._loginStatus = jsonData['loginStatus'];
    this._Status = jsonData['Status'];
    this._DivisionName = jsonData['DivisionName'];
  }
  String get loginStatus => _loginStatus;
  String get Status => _Status;
  String get DivisionName => _DivisionName;
  set DivisionName(String value) {
    _DivisionName = value;
  }
  set Status(String value) {
    _Status = value;
  }
  set loginStatus(String value) {
    _loginStatus = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the only issue but `uri.replace` returns a new `Uri` since `Uri` is immutable. So your `uri.replace(queryParameters: params);` does nothing right now.

Comment: please any give solution

Comment: Can you share your Postman project where it is suppose to work? I have tried replicate a Postman project based on your Dart code and cannot get it to work so there are properly some details missing.

Comment: i have edit my questions and add the postman image.

Comment: You are not sending the parameters as queryParameters but instead as a body...

Comment: please edit my code. i new in flutter

Comment: Ok, give me a minute to rewriting your code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Postman project, you code is incorrect. The main problem is that the parameters is not being sent as GET variables (query parameters) as your code suggests but are instead being sent as a JSON encoded body.

I have rewritten your code so it does the same as your Postman projects suggests:

```
class User {
  String? loginStatus;
  String? status;
  String divisionName;

  User.fromJson(dynamic jsonData)
      : this.loginStatus = jsonData['loginStatus'] as String?,
        this.status = jsonData['Status'] as String?,
        this.divisionName = jsonData['DivisionName'] as String;

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'loginStatus: $loginStatus, status: $status, divisionName: $divisionName';
}

Future<User?> signIn() async {
  final params = utf8.encode(json.encode({
    "username": "XYZ_39510",
    "password": "XYZ_39510",
    "ProjectName": "PPMS"
  }));

  final request = await HttpClient().openUrl(
      'GET', Uri.parse('http://devfield.ppms.co.in/HRMS_WEBAPI/api/login'))
    ..headers.contentType = ContentType.json
    ..headers.contentLength = params.length
    ..add(params);
  //await request.flush();
  final response = await request.close();

  print('---- status code: ${response.statusCode}');
  final jsonData = await response
      .transform(const Utf8Decoder())
      .transform(const JsonDecoder())
      .single;

  if (jsonData != null) {
    final user = User.fromJson((jsonData as List<dynamic>).first)
    print('---- divisionName--->: ${user.divisionName}');
    return user;
  } else {
    //isLoading = false;
    return null;
  }
}
```

I should note that I didn't use the `http` package but instead used `dart:io`. If that is a problem, please tell me and I can try rewrite it.

Comment: Thank you very much its getting 200. Thanks a lot . but how can i get JSON data to save model class.

Comment: You can just remove the line ` .transform(const JsonDecoder())` if you don't want to decode the json here. If you do that, `jsonData` should instead be a `String`.

Comment: Updated the code so it instead get the `String` instead of decoding it into a `Object`.

Comment: jsonData  instead of jsonString right? if (jsonData != null)

Comment: User.fromJson(jsonData) {
    this._loginStatus = jsonData['loginStatus'];
    this._Status = jsonData['Status'];
    this._DivisionName = jsonData['DivisionName'];
  }      //I correct ah in model class

Comment: Ok, it does not really matter. You can just parse the JSON string. I have fixed my example so the names are correct now.

Comment: Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'       // i have this error

Comment: Can you add your `User` class in full in your question?

Comment: i have added user class and to create three string variable only

Comment: Updated example again. Your problem is that you get a `List` in your JSON result with one element. Also, don't make get/set methods unless you need it. Dart is not Java so you can always just add a get/set later.

Comment: Also, `loginStatus` and `status` was `null` in the returned JSON so I have made this fields nullable.

Comment: Works fine for me? Are you sure you did copy all my updated answer? I have updated both `User` and `SignIn`. E.g. this is important `return User.fromJson((jsonData as List<dynamic>).first);`

Comment: sorry just now added , i have working . please print single value. E.g:    print('---- divisionName--->: ${User.divisionName}');
How?

Comment: i a new in flutter i am working couple of weeks only. please support me any doubt. If you feel free please help me. how can you contact please give mobile number or skype id anything . please give.

Comment: Example updated so it prints the `divisionName` of the parsed `User`.

Comment: Yeah working. thanks a lot . please give contact number any contact id.

Comment: Not going to happen sorry. Stackoverflow is really just something I do in my spare time and I think it makes more sense if I can help multiple people instead of just dedicating my spare time to help a single person. There are also lots of tutorials and youtube videos about Dart and Flutter so you should be able to study this yourself and then create stackoverflow questions if there are something specific you want help with.

Comment: sorry. Thanks of the support. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This should work,
instead of using `Uri.parse` use `Uri.http`.

```
sigin(String url) async {
  final base_url = 'devfield.ppms.co.in';
  final path = '/HRMS_WEBAPI/api/login';
  var params = {
    "username": "XYZ_39510",
    "password": "XYZ_39510",
    "ProjectName": "PPMS"
  };
  try {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.http(base_url, path, params),
      headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json"},
    );
    // response

  } catch (e) {
    // error handling
  }
}
```